# Best place to temporarily hold files while packaging software

Tags: linux, software-packaging, appimage

I am looking for what is considered best practice when temporarily storing files and/or directories when generating an AppImage or packaging software.  I am looking for a location that is not restricted by user permissions but is not overtly visible.  I currently have created an AppImage that generates other AppImages for a specific set of applications that can be readily distributed.  I have been storing the AppDir on the desktop so far so that I could easily check the directory and troubleshoot errors.  It currently works as intended and I would like to relocate this location to somewhere that is not clearly visible to the user.  It seems like poor practice to have this temporary directory appear on the desktop just to be deleted shortly after.  I just want the whole process to be as clean as possible.

Comment: Voting to close as "opinion-based" :Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: I have edited the question to better reflect my desire.  Anything anyone has ever said is opinion.  The point of any forum is to promote communication.  If I asked what color is the sky and you replied blue, that would be opinion.  I may not see blue.  Everything is subjective.  In this particular case I asked for exactly what i wanted, an opinion.  there is no right or wrong answer.  i will take suggestions and see what works best for me.  Your OPINION that this should be closed has been noted.  However, it is a valid question that directly requests best practices for a given scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Considering AppImages create their own temporary containers at run-time, I have opted use that space for building the extra AppImages.  I found some other information pointing to using the Temp(tmp) or opt folders on the system as temporary locations, but I cannot say for certain if this is good practice or not.  For my particular situation I believe using the temporary space already created by my AppImage is an appropriate solution.